# Подключение файла в main Golang

Tags: golang

У меня в разных файлах написан основной код и в другой вынесены константы. при попытки подключить файл с константами к основному при билде появляется ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

структура такая:

[image: структура]

подключаю таким образом:

[image: подключение]

как решить проблему ?

Comment: В корневой папке, там где `main.go` выполните команду `go mod init example.org/my_module`. Вместо `example.org/my_module` можете подставить любое имя. Эта команда создаст файл `go.mod`. После этого `GOROOT` не будет использоваться

Comment: go.mod в папке уже есть

Comment: Пардон, я не додумал. У вас в `go.mod` написано `module foo/bar/baz`, тогда вам нужно импортировать пакет `import "foo/bar/baz/include"`. Файл `constant.go` упоминать не нужно, все константы из этого файла принадлежат пакету.

Comment: Таже самая ошибка

Comment: Быть не может. Вы нам что-то недоговариваете. Добавьте в вопрос содержимое `go.mod` (как минимум строку `module ...`) и строку импорта из `main.go` как вы импортируете. А лучше сделайте минимально воспроизводимый пример с простым `main.go` в котором используется константа из `constnant.go`

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишете "та же самая ошибка". Этого не может быть.

Вот пример.

Файл `include/constant.go`:

```
package includ

const (
    HelloWorld = "Hello, World!"
)
```

Файл `go.mod`:

```
module example.org/foo/bar

go 1.19
```

Файл `main.go`:

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "example.org/foo/bar/includ"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(includ.HelloWorld)
}
```

Строка запуска:

```
 go run .
```

Результат:

```
Hello, World!
```

Работает. Ещё раз проверьте, что вы написали в импорте. Должно быть

```
"<имя_модуля>/includ"
```